# Using Starts with to find the key of a List

Tags: java, hashmap, slack

I have a list of objects (Slack Bolt framework), one of them is appended dynamically upstream and then passed in an array list. I need to fetch out this key (it looks like this: `status_block_EPOCH`) but when I try to filter I get undefined in the evaluate expression in IntelliJ. I am trying something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ViewState.Value>> blockValues = viewSubmissionRequest.getPayload().getView().getState().getValues();

blockValues.keySet().stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("status_block")
```

That should give me the key that matches this (i.e. `status_block_123646484568`) that I can use but I cant get it to work for some reason. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you create a [mre]? There's not enough context here to answer.

Comment: Where are you getting undefined at?

Comment: you need to end the stream with a terminal operation - a `collect(Collectors.toList())` in this case, or else you will only have a stream (streams dont process any data if you do not have a terminal operation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are you collecting the filtered values in this manner?

```
List<String> keys = blockValues.keySet().stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith("status_block")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, this `keys`list will contain your key.

This part was missing in the question, so I could not be sure.

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the `toList`, that got what I was looking for!